# How to get values data from child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get last 20 records from firebase? I got:

> dataset: undefined undefined

My firebase looks like this:

[image: firebase]

my code

```
var rootRefData = db.ref().child("users_db/user1/dataset");
rootRefData.once("value", snap => {
    var key = snap.key;
    var timestamp = snap.val().timestamp;
    var log = snap.val().log;
    var custom = "";

    // create line chart
    custom += key + ": " + timestamp + " " + log + "<br />";
    console.log(custom);

    counter++;
    $("#chartsl-container-all").append(custom);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rootRefData = db.ref().child("users_db/user1/dataset");
rootRefData.once("value", snap => {
snap.forEach(function (snapshot) {
var key = snapshot.key;
var timestamp = snapshot.val().timestamp;
var log = snapshot.val().log;
var custom = "";
```

`rootRefData` is at node dataset, since you want to get timestamp and log, then you need to iterate inside the randomid using `forEach` to be able to get those values and the random id.

Comment: thanks, you're the best. it's work, but how to limit last 20 records? order by timestamp

Comment: to limit the last 20, do this  `rootRefData.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(20).once("value", snap => {` okay great!